# Can I show an infographic as vector in android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, vector

I have a big infographic (scroll needed) in vector format and I want to put it in a layout in android.

Can I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: what is a "vector format"?  there are countless ways to define vectors

Comment: I did it on illustrator, I guess I could export it in whatever format android accepts.

Comment: Android doesn't natively support vectors prior to API Level 21 (Lollipop), which uses a variation of the SVG format. OR you can use a 3rd party library (android-svg, svg-android or such) to open SVGs in any Android version, since 2.1+.

Comment: Thank you both. If you put your comment as an answer, I'll give you the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VectorCompat](https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat), a support library for VectorDrawable and AnimatedVectorDrawable with fully backwards compatible with api 14+.